# Использование одного фрагмента и нескольких layout'ов

Tags: android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте!
В своем проекте я использую `ViewPager` и `TabLayout` с 3-мя табами.
Каждый таб (если так можно выразиться) - отдельный фрагмент.
От каждого из 3-х созданных фрагментов мне нужен только `layout`, т.е. мне не требуются классы фрагментов. Как можно использовать один фрагмент и в нем отображать только нужный `layout`, чтобы не было много "пустых" классов?

Код `MainActivity:`

```
package com.nikiz.materialtabs.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.nikiz.materialtabs.R;
import com.nikiz.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment;
import com.nikiz.materialtabs.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import com.nikiz.materialtabs.fragments.TwoFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Код `OneFragment:`

```
package com.nikiz.materialtabs.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.nikiz.materialtabs.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

Код `TwoFragment:`

```
package com.nikiz.materialtabs.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.nikiz.materialtabs.R;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }

}
```

Код `ThreeFragment:`

```
package com.nikiz.materialtabs.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.nikiz.materialtabs.R;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Насколько я понял вам нужно вместо фрагментов в ViewPager отображать разметку? ViewPager это умеет.

Comment: Да. Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, привести пример или отредактировать код выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

  private Context context;

  public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
  }


  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = null;
    switch (position){
      case 0:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, collection, false);
        break;
      case 1:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, collection, false);
        break;
      case 2:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, collection, false);
        break;
    }

    collection.addView(view);
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==object;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
  }
}
```